# Buffering Bytes - Node.js Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I want to receive a wav stream from Node.js (in an add-on). It is implemented like this:

```
readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var obj1 = addon.buffering(chunk);//my addon
});
```

But now I want to buffer this information, and create a copy of original wav. So far I can't populate the new file with bytes.

```
void buffering(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  Local<Object> bufferObj = args[0]->ToObject();
  char *buf = node::Buffer::Data(bufferObj);
  if (i == 0){ fp = fopen("copy.wav", "wb"); i++;}

  fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
  fflush(fp);
  if (i == 3){ fclose(fp); }
  i++;

  Local<String> devolve = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "buffering_success");//C++--->JS
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(devolve);
}
```

I don't understand why, but `sizeof(buf)` is always too small. I think is because of that.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` == `sizeof(char*)` is a compile-time constant. You'll need to find an API that tells you the size of that thing.

Comment: How is that related to C? There is no C code given.

Comment: Fwrite.. Write files in C

Comment: That is no valid C code anyway. `if` is a valid keyword in Python, C, BASIC, Pascal, etc. You also want to add these tags?

Comment: Is C Code with v8.h and node.h implemented

Answer (score 0):

With precious tip of @Mat:

Nodejs:

```
readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log(chunk);
  var size = chunk.length;//<---Size of chunk, thanks Matt
  console.log(size);
  var obj1 = addon.buffering(chunk,size);
  console.log('pass chunk');
});
```

Addon:

```
void buffering(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  int size = args[1]->NumberValue();

  Local<Object> bufferObj = args[0]->ToObject();
  char *buf = node::Buffer::Data(bufferObj);
  if (i == 0){ fp = fopen("copy.wav", "wb"); i++;}

  fwrite(buf, 1, size, fp);
  fflush(fp);
  if (i == 3){ fclose(fp); }
  i++;
  Local<String> devolve = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"buffering_sucess");//C++--->JS
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(devolve);
}
```

I will remove the iterator, to some "generic" solution. It is here because I now the number of iterations that will occur.